# Can't Connect to remote Mysql server in Rails, but I can connect to it with command line client

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I have a remote Mysql server, and got all privileges remotely. Here is the output of "show grants" after I logged in remotely, from local computer:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user@%                                                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*B25E737EE2274D7343BF9DCDF6CAF8DB2EAC17E1' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when I try to use this server in a local rails environment, it says this:

> /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@my_project/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'mysqluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)
>     from /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@my_project/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in`initialize'

Here is my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  username: mysqluser
  password: password
  hostname: 192.10.23.114
  database: db_name
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

What I don't understand is why Mysql thinks my user is from "localhost" when I was actually
using a remote access? Do you guys have any idea on this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `hostname` is incorrect.

It should read:

`host: 192.10.23.114`

Comment: I had originally posted the same answer, but I believe it's incorrect. The `mysql2` gem's client adapter doesn't care if you pass a `:host` or `:hostname` option. https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/master/lib/mysql2/client.rb#L51

Comment: I tried Simon's solution and it worked! As Deefour said, I thought mysql2 accepts :host and :hostname equally, but it turns out it doesn't. Any ip address after :hostname is ignored and mysql2 uses "localhost" instead.

Comment: Deefour, I got the reason now. lastest tag of Mysql2 is 0.3.11 which is what I'm using. In this version the client.rb is like this:
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/blob/f41050ea8bd4e546369e702fb7853e05b6635954/lib/mysql2/client.rb

Answer (score 0):

Tuo,

Additionally, you're going to want to make sure you have the mysql2 gem installed. For more configuration details, please check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: thanks meoww-. I have mysql2 gem installed. In fact if I don't have mysql2, it won't give me an error. :)